# Atualizar componente do JSF através da Bean

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Dentro do meu código tenho duas variáveis chamadas **displayMessage** e **displayImage** que são duas **Strings**, que conforme o método for executando, as mensagens vão sendo atualizadas.
 Na minha ManagedBean as mensagens são atualizadas, mas não encontrei uma forma eficaz para renderizar essas informações na página *xhtml*, a qual para
cada mudança gostaria que as mensagens fossem atualizadas dentro de um *dialog*.

Segue um trecho do meu código abaixo:

```
<p:commandButton value="Buscar" id="pesquisa"
                class="ui-button-custom ui-button-busca"
                action="#{fluxo.veiculos}" process="@form" 
                update="@form" onclick="PF('statusDialog').show();" />

        <p:dialog id="mod" modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status"   
         draggable="false" closable="true">
            <h:form id="idformdialog">              
         <div class="modal-content">                                            
          <p:graphicImage id="displayImage1" url="#{fluxoPeriodo.displayImage}" />
           <h:outputText  id="displayMessage1" value="#{fluxoPeriodo.displayMessage}" />                         
        </div>

        <div  class="modal-content">       

          <p:graphicImage id="displayImage2" url="#{fluxoPeriodo.displayImage2}" />
           <h:outputText id="displayMessage2" value="#{fluxoPeriodo.displayMessage2}" />                

        </div> 

        </h:form>              
        </p:dialog>
```

Ao clicar no botão *Buscar* aparece a *dialog* sobre uma *datatable* enquanto informações são processadas.

Abaixo segue a maneira como gostaria que as informações fossem mostradas na minha *dialog*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer para alcançar essa meta?

Grato, Well

Answer (score 1):

Tente atualizar o seu dialog (`update="mod"`) ao clicar no botão:

```
<p:commandButton value="Buscar" id="pesquisa"
                class="ui-button-custom ui-button-busca"
                action="#{fluxo.veiculos}" process="@form" 
                update="mod" onclick="PF('statusDialog').show();" />
```

- Como o seu botão está fora do dialog, ambos estão em forms diferentes
- No seu código apenas o form onde o botão está inserido será atualizado

> Precisa ver se há um form dentro do outro, esse é uma prática perigosa
>   e não recomendável
>
> Coloque seu `dialog` (que contém um `form`) fora do `form` com o botão

---

#### Atualização após resposta:

No seu ManagedBean há um método chamado `veiculos()` onde são processadas as etapas do processamento. Sugiro que após cada etapa concluída você faça uma atualização ajax via backbean. Na versão 6.1 do Primefaces você pode utilizar esse função:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("mod");
```

Se atualizar o seu Primefaces para a versão 6.2 ou superior faça assim:

```
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("mod");
```

Exemplo de como seu código ficaria:

```
public void veiculos() {
    executarProcedimento1();
    atualizarModal();
    executarProcedimento2();
    atualizarModal();
    executarProcedimento3();
    atualizarModal();
    executarProcedimento4();
    atualizarModal();
}

private void atualizarModal() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("mod");
}
```

Não sei se isso será suficiente para você ter o efeito visual que você deseja, dependendo do tempo de processamento a velocidade de atualização será quase imediata. Talvez necessite de ajustes para ficar exatamente como o desejado, mas já é um caminho.

Comment: Melhorou bastante, mas ainda não cheguei no meu objetivo. O que acontece é que aparece a mensagem do ultimo equipamento assim que finaliza a execução do método.
 Eu gostaria que durante o processo, as informações de troca de equipamento ficassem aparecendo na minha *dialog*, por exemplo: 

Equipamento 3 processado!
Equipamento 4 em processo ...

Em seguida atualizasse:

Equipamento 4 processado
Equipamento 5 em processo.

Obrigado

Comment: @WellSilva Qual versão do Primefaces você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando API 6.1

Comment: @WellSilva resposta atualizada, verifique se ajudou, por favor.

Comment: Vou verificar obrigado.

Comment: Ele tomou efeito dessa forma:  public void updateForm() {
    
       RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idformdialog:displayImage1");
       RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idformdialog:displayMessage1");       
       RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idformdialog:displayImage2");
       RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idformdialog:displayMessage2");
       
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Success", "Success"));
      }

Comment: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("mod"); 
Não obteve sucesso dessa forma. Mas mesmo eu colocando a execução em alguns trechos do código ele atualizou status do ultimo equipamento, quando a execução do método acabou.
 Tem que haver uma forma de fazer isso, como você mesmo disse é um caminho, grande caminho, me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Meu método é executado dentro de um **FOR**, o que acontece, ele faz 4 equipamentos caso selecione 4, mas mostra apenas o ultimo, quando na verdade meu objetivo é ele chegar a mostrar o processo de um por um.

Comment: Será necessário orquestrar essas chamadas para conseguir o efeito desejado

Comment: Exato estava pensando nisso ... Ele só faz quando termina o método.
Vou trabalhando no método e logo chegar até uma resposta conclusiva.
Posto aqui.